# problem with browsers Firefox and Chrome when printing a page?

Tags: html, css, printing, height, border

I've faced a weird behavior from browsers like *Firefox & Chrome* when I  want to print a page where there is a table with a fixed height *500px* sometimes browser remove the height completely ([Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwgwq.jpg)) sometimes it remains the height but removes borders([Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qi9L.jpg))!

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
main{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    border: 1px solid !important;
    width: 100%;
}
tr,th,td{
    border: 1px solid !important;
    padding: 3px;
}
.minHeight{
    height: 500px !important;
}
@media print {
    table {
        border: 1px solid !important;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid !important;
    }
    
    .minHeight{
        height: 500px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Code Article</th>
            <th>Code TVA</th>
            <th>Remise</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="minHeight">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have an idea Why and How this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved it! After struggling for about two hours I discover two nice tricks one for fixing problems at *Chrome*: or just specify height at **`<tbody class="minHeight" style="height: 720px">`**

```css
table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And about *Firefox* I found out that it's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1394249) I solve it by giving *`table`* *attribute* `cellspacing="0"` and in `CSS` style `border-collapse:initial;`