# How to set height of tbody and let rows at top not at the center?

Tags: html, css, height

How can let the rows at the top *(not at the bottom)* with fixed `tbody` *height* of `500px`!

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
main{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
}
tr,th,td{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.minHeight{
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code Article</th>
      <th>Code TVA</th>
      <th>Remise</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="minHeight">
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would clarify it as I get output like this:

[image]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for asking to clarify, I've updated the question with images I hope it's clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `text-align:center` on the `td` and add `vertical-align:top`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

main {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 3px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.minHeight {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code Article</th>
      <th>Code TVA</th>
      <th>Remise</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="minHeight">
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but when I want to print the page I encounter [a weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70784428/problem-with-browsers-firefox-and-chrome-when-printing-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You are not very descriptive on what you want but I'll give it a try.

---

I think you mean that you want the numbers on top of the list under the name and not in the center of it's entire box.

If so, then one simple solution is to add padding to the bottom of your first row of data (td). The padding should be equal to the height of your liking *(warning: if you add more data you will need to adjust the padding)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I think you don't get what I want, I've updated the question with images I hope it's more descriptive now!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).