# How to make vertical line in cell to match height of table made with flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, flexbox

I want to make a `table` with HTML using flexbox, not `table tag` since I've encountered a [weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70784428/problem-with-browsers-firefox-and-chrome-when-printing-a-page) when I wanted to print a page on *chrome* the height of `tbody` in *table* reduced to fit its width, which is something I don't want I want to keep him with fixed height, that's why I went using flex at least I've control of setting height!

But here's the issue I faced again:

[image]

I want the borders of cell either *left or right* cells keeps the height of table body till the end;
That's I've used `JS` looping and creating *empty cells* just to imitate space of height but I think it's not the best approach, it breaks the borders of `table` and go beyond or more than it should take. here's picture of what happen look at the bottom of table:

[image]

```js
let iLogic = 0,
  rowsNew = "";
while (iLogic <= 29) {
  rowsNew += `<div class="row">
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cell-td">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  `;
  iLogic++;
}

document.querySelector(".template").innerHTML += rowsNew;
```

```css
.table {
    height: 808px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .row .cell-th {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .row .cell-th {
    border: 1px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
    width: 10%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
  }
  .row .cell-td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
  }
  /*Designation*/
  .row .cell-th:nth-child(3),.row .cell-td:nth-child(3){
      width: 50%;
  }
  .row .cell-th:nth-child(4),.row .cell-td:nth-child(4){
      width: 5%;
  }
  /*Code Article*/
  .row .cell-th:nth-child(1),.row .cell-td:nth-child(1){
      width: 15%;
  }
  /*Code TVA*/
  .row .cell-th:nth-child(2),.row .cell-td:nth-child(2){
      width: 5%;
  }
  /*Remise*/
  .row .cell-th:nth-child(6),.row .cell-td:nth-child(6){
      width: 7%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell-th">Code Article</div>
            <div class="cell-th">Code TVA</div>
            <div class="cell-th">Désignation</div>
            <div class="cell-th">Qté</div>
            <div class="cell-th">P.U.TTC</div>
            <div class="cell-th">Remise</div>
            <div class="cell-th">Montant TTC</div>
          </div>
          <div class="template"> <div class="row">
            <div class="cell-td">DV21-10030</div>
            <div class="cell-td">20</div>
            <div class="cell-td">LIT ELECTRIQUE HAYDN  AVEC BARRIERE BOIS MILANO + POTENCE</div>
            <div class="cell-td">1</div>
            <div class="cell-td">15 800,00</div>
            <div class="cell-td">0</div>
            <div class="cell-td">15 800,00</div>
          </div> <div class="row">
            <div class="cell-td">DV21-10030</div>
            <div class="cell-td">20</div>
            <div class="cell-td">MATELAS GAUFRIER MONO-PORTANCE AVEC HOUSE ZIPPEE SUR COTES</div>
            <div class="cell-td">1</div>
            <div class="cell-td">2 450,00</div>
            <div class="cell-td">0</div>
            <div class="cell-td">2 450,00</div>
          </div> <div class="row">
            <div class="cell-td">DV21-10030</div>
            <div class="cell-td">20</div>
            <div class="cell-td">FRAIS DE TRANSPORT</div>
            <div class="cell-td">300</div>
            <div class="cell-td">1,00</div>
            <div class="cell-td">0</div>
            <div class="cell-td">299,999</div>
          </div></div>
        </div>
```

i'd be appreciated if you could help me reaching a solution!

Comment: your table is responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's your idea about this solution ?

but it has a bug and that's when the window is resizing!!!

```js
let setHeight = function () {
  let hieghts = [];
  let classes = 1;
  let rowNum = document.querySelector("#desc").childElementCount;
  for (classes; classes < rowNum; classes++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.content${classes}`).forEach((td) => {
      hieghts.push(td.clientHeight);
    });
    let max = Math.max(...hieghts);
    document.querySelectorAll(`.content${classes}`).forEach((td) => {
      td.style.height = `${max}px`;
    });
    max = 0;
    hieghts = [];
  }
};
window.onresize = setHeight;  // why this line not work ???

setHeight();
```

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.cells {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells  title">code title 1</span>
    <span class="cells content1">dev-1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">dev-2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">dev-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells  title">code </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="desc" class="col">
    <span class="cells content title">description</span>
    <span class="cells content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </span>
    <span class="cells content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore </span>
    <span class="cells content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectedgdg gdgdfg fgdfg dfgdfgd dgdfgdfg dfhd h h fgghg fghf hghhfem ipsum dolor sit amet consectedgdg gdgdfg fgdfg dfgdfgd dgdfgdfg dfhd h h fgghg fghf hghhfhh ftur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells  title">num</span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">1</span>
    <span class="cells content3">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells  title">prise</span>
    <span class="cells content1">100</span>
    <span class="cells content2">200</span>
    <span class="cells content3">300</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells  title">total </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1000</span>
    <span class="cells content2">20000</span>
    <span class="cells content3">15000</span>
  </div>
</div>
```